# How to avoid duplicate entries in SCSS/SASS?

Tags: css, sass

I have recently started working with SASS in combination with Eclipse at work, and everything's working peachy:
Building an application through Ant executes a *.bat* which runs a *Ruby command line* which compiles any relevant *.scss* files into *.css* files.
One thing we've noticed however is that there can be duplicates. Granted, the general *.css* overrule rules apply (last one first), but having x-amount of the same statement is quite redundant. Take a a look at the following example of compiles *.css* code (it's not perfect, I was merely testing something)

```
/* line 2, ../../../sass/common/style.scss */
nav ul {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  list-style: none;
}
/* line 8, ../../../sass/common/style.scss */
nav li {
  display: inline-block;
}
/* line 9, ../../../sass/common/style.scss */
nav li {
  display: inline-block;
}
/* line 11, ../../../sass/common/style.scss */
nav a {
  display: block;
  padding: 6px 12px;
  text-decoration: none;
}

/* line 1, ../../../sass/webshop/_button-style.scss */
div:hover {
  padding: 12px 12px;
}

/* line 5, ../../../sass/webshop/_button-style.scss */
img {
  padding: 12px 24px;
}

/* line 2, ../../../sass/webshop/_webshop-style.scss */
nav ul {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  list-style: none;
}
/* line 8, ../../../sass/webshop/_webshop-style.scss */
nav li {
  display: inline-block;
}
/* line 9, ../../../sass/webshop/_webshop-style.scss */
nav li {
  display: inline-block;
}
/* line 11, ../../../sass/webshop/_webshop-style.scss */
nav a {
  display: block;
  padding: 6px 12px;
  text-decoration: none;
}

/* line 18, ../../../sass/webshop/_webshop-style.scss */
div:hover {
  padding: 12px 12px;
}
```

In this test **style.scss** contains the main styling for the webshop, **_button-style.scss** for any buttons present and **_webshop-style** contains any *overrules* for **style.scss**.As you can see, there are duplicates from *style.scss* and *_webshop-style.scss* present in this file, which is something we'd rather avoid. Can this be avoided? If yes: How?; If no: Is there a workaround/manual method to avoid this?

***NOTE: _button-style.css is of no importance to this question/problem. It's just here to show you in a complete way what I'm doing.***

For further reference, here's some important files:

**config:**

```
require 'compass/import-once/activate'
require "sass-globbing"
# Require any additional compass plugins here.

# Set this to the root of your project when deployed:
#http_path = "/"
css_dir = "../webapp/static/css"
sass_dir = "common"
add_import_path = "../webshop/"
images_dir = "images"
javascripts_dir = "javascripts"
```

**style.scss:**

```
nav {
  ul {
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    list-style: none;
  }

  li { display: inline-block; }
  li { display: inline-block; }

  a {
    display: block;
    padding: 6px 12px;
    text-decoration: none;
  }
}

@import "../webshop/_*";
```

**_webshop-style.scss:**

```
nav {
  ul {
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    list-style: none;
  }

  li { display: inline-block; }
  li { display: inline-block; }

  a {
    display: block;
    padding: 6px 12px;
    text-decoration: none;
  }
}

div:hover {
  padding: 12px 12px;
}
```

Answer (score 3):

Sass will not attempt to remove any styling, ever, under any circumstance (only empty selectors and whitespace/comments are removed, depending on the chosen output style).  Sass has no way of knowing if you are overriding previous declarations with a different selector (eg. `.foo .bar` and `p.bar` might match the same element), so it writes things out exactly as you specified.

If you want to continue writing/using duplicate declarations in your Sass, you will need to use a 3rd party tool (eg. linter) to remove them.

Comment: Thank you for the comment. I feared SASS would not do it automatically. I'll look into this tool you mentioned.

Comment: Just to give a little update: I'm waiting for an official confirmation from my boss to see where we're headed, as a linter isn't helpful when 'cleaning up' the compiled _css_ file.